# SUM of MySQL data called WEIGHT

Tags: php, pdo, crud

### Hello from South Africa!

Silly newby question here.

I have a php app that basically captures weight of disposed electronics daily. I am trying to display the weight in Kilograms (KG) for the day as a sum of all the weights captured. So if there are 10 rows, each with say 10KG, i want the total KG to display at 100KG.

Heres my code:

```
$hostname="localhost";
$username="ecemsapp";
$password="C3m3t3ry!@";
$db = "ecemsapp";
$dbh = new PDO("MySQL:host=$hostname;dbname=$db", $username, $password);
foreach($dbh->query('SELECT SUM(weight) 
FROM subgrade_bin') as $row) {
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row['SUM(weight)'] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>"; 
}
?>
```

But it is throwing the follwing error

```
Uncaught PDOException: could not find driver in /www/wwwroot/EMITTED-FOR-SECURITY-REASON/admin/admin_home.php:193 Stack trace: #0 /www/wwwroot/EMITTED-FOR-SECURITY-REASON/admin/admin_home.php(193): PDO->__construct() #1 {main} thrown in
/www/wwwroot/EMITTED-FOR-SECURITY-REASON/admin/admin_home.php
on line
193
```

This is actually for work (yes i took on the project with little knowledge). Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: `MySQL:` should  be `mysql:`. It's case-sensitive.

Comment: The error is happening on the `new PDO` line, it has nothing to do with the query.

Comment: @Barmar Thank you it was MySQL to mysql case sensitive. It works now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: MYSQL is case sensitive. Changed to mysql and it worked.

```
 <?php
$hostname="localhost";
$username="USERNAME";
$password="PASSWORD";
$db = "DATABASE";
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$db", $username, $password);
foreach($dbh->query('SELECT SUM(weight) 
FROM subgrade_bin') as $row) {
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row['SUM(weight)'] . "</td>". " KG";
echo "</tr>"; 
}
?>
```